# How to Convert a structure from Matlab code to C code (using Matlab Compiler)

Tags: c, matlab, structure, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have been trying to create a C Shared Library using Matlab compiler that will be used as a plug in library to a different application for a while now. I recently thought I had completed this task only to realize that the function I was calling from my newly "Matlab Compiled" Shared Library needed to convert its return to a C structure.

I used the example found on the Matlab Answers site to help me create the wrapper level2 function to call my Matlab function which needs to return a structure.(http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94715-how-do-i-wrap-matlab-compiler-4-8-r2008a-created-c-dlls-to-create-another-dll)

My issue is at the *Convert returned  MATLAB data to C data* part of the code found below. I can convert to ints, doubles, chars, etc. fine, but I am having trouble figuring out how to code the conversion from an mxArray returned by matlab to a C structure.

```
/* Wrapper for level 1 function exported by the MATLAB generated DLL         *
 * This function converts C data to MATLAB data, calls the MATLAB generated  *
 * function in level1.dll and then converts the MATLAB data back into C data */

int wmlfLevel1(double* input2D, int size, char* message, double** output2d){
    int nargout=1;

    /* Pointers to MATLAB data */
    mxArray *msg;
    mxArray *in2d;
    mxArray *out2d=NULL;

    /* Start MCR, load library if not done already */
    int returnval=isMCRrunning();
    if(!returnval)
        return returnval;

    /* Convert C data to MATLAB data */
    /* IMPORTANT: this has to be done after ensuring that the MCR is running */
    msg=mxCreateString(message);
    in2d=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(size, size, mxREAL);
    memcpy(mxGetPr(in2d), input2D, size*size*sizeof(double));

    /* Call the M function */
    returnval=mlfLevel1(nargout, &out2d, in2d, msg);

    /*Convert returned  MATLAB data to C data */
    *output2d=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*size*size);
    memcpy(*output2d, mxGetPr(out2d), size*size*sizeof(double));

    /* Clean up MATLAB variables */
    mxDestroyArray(msg);
    mxDestroyArray(in2d);
    mxDestroyArray(out2d);

    return returnval;
}
```

So far I have tried using the mxCreateStructMatrix function, I tried creating a C structure skeleton, i am about to try the libstruct function, but as I am new to C Programming and the Matlab compiler any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mxGetPr` is simply returning a pointer to a buffer of doubles. The `malloc` call is allocating enough space to store size^2 doubles. `memcpy` is copying the data from out2d's internal storage and into your buffer.

The buffer is one-dimensional, so you'll have to compute the index based on the row and column. You can use something like `output2d[col * size + row]` to access a specific value. (That may be transposed - I don't have access to the docs right now.)

When you're completely done with `output2d`, you'll need to call `free(output2d)` to deallocate the memory, otherwise your code will have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks Katie, I have a few more questions I need clarified.

Do I need to change the malloc call to allocate space according to the type struct, since that is the type I want my data to be stored in. I want my data copied from out2d into structure similar to the one below, how would this change my code? Do I need to set up a C structure first and then use memcpy to move my out2d data into it?

'struct output2d { 
int variable1;
double vairable2;
char variable3[10];
}'

Comment: Your structure will need space to store the data. If you don't know `size` beforehand, you'll still need to `malloc` it. (If you do know it, then you can declare a fixed size 2-dimensional array.) The struct should contain something like `double* matrix` element for your data. Then you can do `output2d.matrix = malloc(sizeof(double) * size * size)` and `memcpy(output2d.matrix, mxGetPtr...`.

Comment: I used this example to show my problem, in my code I calculate a structure with 13 data fields some of them simply integers some are  arrays (matrices in Matlab) and one is a string. If I defined the structure first would  I then perform a `output2d.element1 = malloc(sizeof(element1'stype)*size*size)), memcpy(output2d.element1,mxGetpr(out2d)...` and repeat for all 13 fields?

Comment: Matlab structs are dynamic and use strings to identify fields. If you want mlfLevel1 to output to a struct, then you have to disassemble the matlab struct and re-assemble it into a C struct. I don't encourage the use of malloc in this case, try mxMalloc: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxmalloc.html?refresh=true

Comment: @user3528438, thanks for the tip, I went ahead and substituted that where necessary and decided to just have mlfLevel1 return the data in individual variables and then assign those values to a C struct. I'm assuming that is what you meant by disassembling the Matlab structure and re-assembling it into a C struct. Either way I figured a way around my problem thanks to you so Cheers!